# datetimelike error with perfectly fine timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I am getting the error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` when trying to round the time to 30 min steps, but I don't see why. I have another dataframe with the exact same timestamps and there's no problem with that one.

```
for hobo in loggers_hobo:
    
    df = pd.read_csv(path_input+hobo+ext, skiprows=[0])
    df.rename(columns={'Date Time, GMT+01:00': 'TIMESTAMP', 'Abs Pres, psi (LGR S/N: '+hobo+', SEN S/N: '+hobo+')': 'Pressure_TOT_'+hobo, 'Temp, °F (LGR S/N: '+hobo+', SEN S/N: '+hobo+')': 'Temperature'}, inplace=True)
    df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.round('30min') 
    df.drop(['#', 'Coupler Detached (LGR S/N: '+hobo+')', 'Coupler Attached (LGR S/N: '+hobo+')', 'Host Connected (LGR S/N: '+hobo+')', 'End Of File (LGR S/N: '+hobo+')'], inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.to_csv(path_temp+hobo+ext)
    print(df)
```

Dataframe after editing:

```
                 TIMESTAMP  Pressure_TOT_20796630  Temperature
0      2022-03-11 14:10:00                14.8332       75.659
1      2022-03-11 14:10:22                    NaN          NaN
2      2022-03-11 14:18:58                    NaN          NaN
3      2022-03-11 14:19:54                    NaN          NaN
4      2022-03-11 14:20:58                    NaN          NaN
                   ...                    ...          ...
16094  2023-02-09 12:40:00                16.5452       42.363
16095  2023-02-09 13:10:00                16.5363       42.179
16096  2023-02-09 13:20:36                    NaN          NaN
16097  2023-02-09 13:20:43                    NaN          NaN
16098  2023-02-09 13:20:58                    NaN          NaN
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Hard to answer this without seeing the data that is read by read_csv.

Comment: I've added the looks of the dataframe, guessing that's what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is need rounding datetimes, not strings after `strftime`, so instead:

```
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.round('30min')
```

use:

```
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP']).dt.round('30min').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```